# @ManyToOne and @BatchSize

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I found in some old code strange thing (at least for me).

The field which is annotated `@ManyToOne` is also annotated with `@BatchSize`.

I always thought that `@BatchSize` annotation only affects when annotated at class level or on a collection (`@OneToMany`) and affects **pre-fetching** when iterating.

But maybe I am wrong and annotating `@ManyToOne` with `@BatchSize` affects something. I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Does annotating `@ManyToOne` with `@BatchSize` have sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@ManyToOne` associated with `@BatchSize` could make sense only if the corresponding field is marked as `lazy` (`lazy=true`).

Indeed, if the field is not `lazy`, it's by definition already loaded since the enclosing entity is loaded, so the problem of database calls doesn't apply.

Imagine a `Person` class who has a collection of `ShoesPair` element (`ShoesPair`.class) and within this one is present an `owner` field marked as lazy (since optional and not really bringing an important information when retrieving a specific pair of shoes).

One wants to iterate through **25** pair of shoes (25 `ShoesPair` objects) in order to retrieve their owner.

If the `owner` field (corresponding to one person) is only annotated with `@ManyToOne`, there would be **25** select to database.

However, if annoted with `@BatchSize(size=5)`, there would be merely **5** calls and so increasing performance.

From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch), it is precised that batch size does not only apply with collections:

> You can **also** enable batch fetching of collections.

Hibenate mentions especially `@OneToMany` cases, because these one are applied with fields that are in 90% of cases marked as `lazy`.

Comment: If it really works like you wrote that is ok with me. But I couldn't find it in the documentation. There I see only this: "19.1.5. Using batch fetching

Using batch fetching, Hibernate can load several uninitialized proxies if one proxy is accessed. Batch fetching is an optimization of the lazy select fetching strategy. There are two ways you can configure batch fetching: on the class level and the collection level."

Comment: I mean the fragment :  on the class level and the collection level.

Comment: @Łukasz Rzeszotarski I think that is considered as pretty obvious by the documentation and that's why it's not mentioned. Indeed, the concept applies only on lazy objects. I updated my answer.

Comment: Maybe obvious maybe not. The documentation should cover all possibilities or just be written in more general way - like you wrote 'the concept applies to lazy objects'. But thanks for the answer I'm gonna accept it, but maybe someone wants to add something yet.

Comment: But in the documentation, it's explained a similar example with an `owner` field. This one could be marked as nothing as `@ManyToOne` (no matters). According to me, your demand is included into this example.

Comment: I found this not to be true in my case, which matches what @chris explains in his comment.

Comment: It was not clear to me from the response nor the comments where to place the annotation. This answer to a similar question explains it more clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734286/2018219

Answer (score 20):

I think the question refers to combining `@ManyToOne` and `@BatchSize` on the same field, e.g.:

```
@ManyToOne
@BatchSize(size = 5)
private User owner;
```

This use case is not supported by Hibernate, at least when using annotations. The only uses of batch fetching mentioned by the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch) are:

- On collection fields, i.e., `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` (but *not* `@ManyToOne`)
- On the entity class to be fetched

E.g.:

```
@Entity
@BatchSize(size = 5)
public class User {
  ...
}
```

This latter case enables batching for all relationships of type User, including many-to-one relationships. However, with the annotation on the entity class it is not possible to control the behaviour on a field-by-field basis.

A search through the Hibernate source code for all uses of `@BatchSize` confirms the lack of support for your usage. From what I see in [AnnotationBinder.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationBinder.java), the `@BatchSize` annotation is only inspected on the entity class and on fields which have some kind of `@XxxToMany` annotation.

Comment: I find your answer very interesting. It seems to contradict the one accepted by the OP. I'm not checking your research but you have me convinced so I'm upvoting your answer. It would be cool if an expert could settle this.

Comment: I don't consider myself an "expert", but I can confirm the Entity annotation works.

Answer (score -1):

Solving N+1 query problem with Hibernate

1 Using Criteria queries with fetchMode

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("contact", FetchMode.EAGER);

2 HOL fetch join

3 @BatchSize

The @BatchSize annotation can be used to define how many identical associations to populate in a single database query. If the session has 100 customers attached to it and the mapping of the 'contact' collection is annotated with @BatchSize of size n. It means that whenever Hibernate needs to populate a lazy contact collection it checks the session and if it has more customers which their contact collections need to be populated it fetches up to n collections.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @BatchSize(size=25)
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
```