# @BatchSize but many round trips when fetching a @ManyToOne association

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, jpa

I use pagination with hibernate spring-data-jpa and querydsl and i use `@BatchSize(size=10)` to make just one round-trip to the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appel_offre", catalog = "ao")
public class AppelOffre implements java.io.Serializable {

    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "appelOffre")
    @BatchSize(size=10)
    public Set<AoActivite> getAoActivites() {
        return this.aoActivites;
    }
```

and :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ao_activite", catalog = "ao")
public class AoActivite implements java.io.Serializable {
    .....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ACTIVITE", nullable = false)
    @BatchSize(size=10)
    public Activite getActivite() {
        return this.activite;
    }
```

my query

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(ao) 

    .leftJoin( ao.acheteur, ach ).fetch()

    .leftJoin( ao.aoActivites , ao_ac )
    .leftJoin( ao_ac.activite , ac )
    .offset(...).limit(...).list(..);
```

but in the log got many round trip to the database:

```
1 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.ao_activite aoactivite0_ where aoactivite0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

2 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

3 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

4 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

5 - round-trip

.....

6 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

7 - round-trip

......

8 - round-trip

.....
Hibernate: select ... from ao.activite activite0_ where activite0_.ID_ACTIVITE=?

9 - round-trip

.....

10 - round-trip
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `@BatchSize` makes sense on both

- `One-To-Many` and
- `Many-to-One` as well

Just in case of `Many-To-One`, we have to apply it on `@Entity` level (in our case on mapping of the `Activite` class)

```
@Entity
@BatchSize(size=25)
@Table(name = "activite" ...
public class Activite implements java.io.Serializable {
...
```

Check it here in doc *(small cite appended below)*:

#### [20.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-batch)

> ...
>
> Batch fetching for classes/entities is easier to understand. Consider the following example: at runtime you have 25 Cat instances loaded in a Session, and each `Cat` has a reference to its owner, a Person. The `Person` class is mapped with a proxy, lazy="true". If you now iterate through all cats and call `getOwner()` on each, Hibernate will, by default, execute 25 SELECT statements to retrieve the proxied owners. You can tune this behavior by specifying a batch-size in the mapping of Person:

```
<class name="Person" batch-size="10">...</class>
```

> ...

Comment: I will try it soon as possible.

Comment: Great to see that, enjoy amazing Hibernate Youssef ;)

Answer (score 8):

1. `@BatchSize` makes more sense for [to-many associations (e.g. `@OneToMany`)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection), not for to-one relations.
2. With batch fetching, you have (M/N + 1) database roundtrips, where M is the number of children entities in your uninitialized to-many association and N is the batch size.
3. If you want one and only one secondary database roundtrip, you need to use [sub-select fetching](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#SUBSELECT).
4. For to-one associations (e.g. `@ManyToOne`) use [JPQL or Criteria JOIN FETCH instead](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

Comment: 4 - I cant use `join fetch` if i use pagination. 3 - `sub-select fetching` i think work also just for to-many associations e.g just for collection.

Comment: But the JPA query already supports .fetch(), right? As for 3. It's for collections if you want to fetch those as well.

Comment: Yes it works with fetch but with pagination offset () limit () there is a memory problem if we fetch collection.

Comment: It depends on how large the to-many collection is. That's why I said to use sub-select fetching, instead of joining. When combining collection join fetches with pagination, Hibernate resembles to fetching the whole collection to make sure that children associations are not truncated.

Comment: I will try it and see if it usefull in my case.

Comment: i understand now what u mean but in my case i want to fetch just 10 collection not the all the collections and fetch sub select i think don't work for to-one associations. @RadimKöhler explain in its answer that batch size work also for to-one relations

Comment: I am glad you found what you were searching for.