# Why Hibernate sometimes ignores FetchMode.JOIN?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, optimization

I have an entity with a `@ManyToOne` relation, which I'd like to retrieve with a single query, thus using `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`. Sometimes Hibernate doesn't respect that and issues N+1 `SELECT`s. With *sometimes* I mean that since I don't know what triggers it, I have cases which on the same class for different queries this could happen or not.

This is a simplified entity with the annotations I use:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Department department;

}
```

With

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);

Root<Employee> root = criteriqQuery.from(Employee.class);

TypedQuery<Employee> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Employee> employees = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

I would expect a single query to fetch both `Employee` and its `Department`, something like

```
select ... from Employee join Department on ...
```

instead I get a first select for all N `Employee`s and then N `SELECT`s for all `Department`s (consider no cache).

I've found many similar questions, but their answers suggest workarounds and do not explain why this is happening. Please, avoid answers suggesting to use lazy loading: it's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rule is quite simple: Queries ignore fetch modes. When you write a query, you are telling what is joined and what is not joined.

Fetch mode is only taken into account when entity is loaded with methods like `EntityManager.find(class, id)` or when navigating through some other entity graph and loading its associations.

Comment: Thank you! That was it: the Criteria API ignores `@Fetch`, but using `Root.fetch()` (which is JPA) I can achieve the same result.

Comment: @GiovanniLovato Thank you for the hint, that `Root.fetch` achieves the same result - that was very helpful. I only have to add, that the resulting `Fetch` can be casted to `Join` for further use. See also this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17307248/7095884