# Hibernate FetchMode.JOIN vs FetchMode.SUBSELECT

Tags: hibernate

I have a `@OneToMany` relationship and am using Hibernate 5.3.7 to write an EAGER fetch. I realize EAGER fetching is an anti-pattern, this is a very specific use case. According to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-fetchmode) I can use `FetchMode.JOIN` in my `TypedQuery` and Hibernate should create a nice query for me, however, I saw it spam a few dozen select statements.  It wasn't until I changed this to `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` that it condensed the query into one select statement.  I realize this is similar to [Why Hibernate sometimes ignores FetchMode.JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796798/why-hibernate-sometimes-ignores-fetchmode-join), however, I don't understand why `FetchMode.JOIN` did not work since this is all within a Hibernate query.  Any ideas?

Below are the annotations I'm using on the `OneToMany` side:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "auto", schema = "us")
public class Auto extends AbstractTable {

   /** Ordered list of tires. */
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auto", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<Tire> tires;
   ...
}
```

I am using SpringBoot with `@PersistenceContext` to get my `EntityManager`.  The Auto has a bi-directional `OneToOne` relationship with its containing class AutoOwnerThing.

```java
final String queryString = "FROM AutoOwnerThing e JOIN FETCH e.auto WHERE e.id in :ids";
TypedQuery<AutoOwnerThing> = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, AutoOwnerThing.class);
```

Comment: What is your way to fetch Auto ?

Comment: @J.T. What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @J.T. and could you describe a method how you load an entity? Is it `EntityManager.find(class, id)`?

Comment: @SternK I'm using Hibernate 5.3.7

Comment: @antoine.lange My query is asking for Auto as a FETCH JOIN to something else... maybe that's my problem?  I'll update the original post with more information.

Comment: As Dragan said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796798/why-hibernate-sometimes-ignores-fetchmode-join, if you are using Query or TypedQuery to fetch your data, the annotation @Fetch is not considered, as you control the fetch of your data

Comment: @antoine.lange That is my confusion!  In that post it says the Fetch is not considered, so I don't understand why using FetchMode.SUBSELECT made such a difference.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the Dragan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36797931/6277104) is not completely correct.

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join):

> The reason why we are not using a JPQL query to fetch multiple `Department` entities is because the `FetchMode.JOIN` strategy would be overridden by the query fetching directive.
>
> To fetch multiple relationships with a JPQL query, the `JOIN FETCH` directive must be used instead.
>
> Therefore, `FetchMode.JOIN` is useful for when entities are fetched directly, via their identifier or natural-id.
>
> Also, the `FetchMode.JOIN` acts as a `FetchType.EAGER` strategy. Even if we mark the association as `FetchType.LAZY`, the `FetchMode.JOIN` will load the association eagerly.

But, [FetchMode.SUBSELECT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-subselect) can be applied to hql/jpql.

Imagine we have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
public class Department
{
   // ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

and then we run the following query:

```java
List<Department> deps = session.createQuery(
   "select d from Department d where d.id in :ids", Department.class)
.setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(1L, 2L)).getResultList();
```

The `AbstractCollectionPersister.getAppropriateInitializer` [method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/collection/AbstractCollectionPersister.java) will use the `org.hibernate.loader.collection.SubselectOneToManyLoader(Department.employees)` loader. However, without the `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` annotation will be used the `org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.CollectionLoader(Department.employees)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you for editing my post for readability, I like the changes.