# Hibernate is making extra SQL statement with @ManyToOne and @Lazy fetching object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I would like someone to explain me why Hibernate is making one extra SQL statement in my straight forward case. Basically i have this object:

```
@Entity
class ConfigurationTechLog (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long?,

        val configurationId: Long,

        val type: String,

        val value: String?
) {
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "configurationId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        val configuration: Configuration? = null
}
```

So as you can see, nothing special there. And when i execute this query :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM ConfigurationTechLog c where c.id = 10")
fun findById10() : Set<ConfigurationTechLog>
```

In my console i see this:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* SELECT
        c 
    FROM
        ConfigurationTechLog c 
    where
        c.id = 10 */ select
            configurat0_.id as id1_2_,
            configurat0_.configuration_id as configur2_2_,
            configurat0_.type as type3_2_,
            configurat0_.value as value4_2_ 
        from
            configuration_tech_log configurat0_ 
        where
            configurat0_.id=10
Hibernate: 
    select
        configurat0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        configurat0_.branch_code as branch_c2_0_0_,
        configurat0_.country as country3_0_0_,
        configurat0_.merchant_name as merchant4_0_0_,
        configurat0_.merchant_number as merchant5_0_0_,
        configurat0_.org as org6_0_0_,
        configurat0_.outlet_id as outlet_i7_0_0_,
        configurat0_.platform_merchant_account_name as platform8_0_0_,
        configurat0_.store_type as store_ty9_0_0_,
        configurat0_.terminal_count as termina10_0_0_ 
    from
        configuration configurat0_ 
    where
        configurat0_.id=?
```

Can someone please explain me, what is happening here ? From where this second query is coming from ?

Comment: Does anything change when you use `optional = false` with `@ManyToOne`? It might be Hibernate simply doesn't respect the `FetchType.LAZY` hint in this case

Comment: It is same again with optional=true/false.... This really annoys me..

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce this.
Could you add an example of how you use it to see what triggers these additional queries?

Comment: Literally like i explained in question, nothing special i just inject repository in controller and use directly repostiory.findById10(), really straight forward... I was able to reproduce this on my "real" project, and out of curiosity i created a new project just to test this, and i was able to reproduce it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Link can be useful for understand what kind (common) problem is that [N + 1 Problem](https://www.javacodemonk.com/what-is-n-1-problem-in-hibernate-how-will-you-identify-and-solve-it-894097b9)

---

Let me give you an example:

I have three Courses and each of them have Students related.
I would like to perform a "SELECT * FROM Courses". This is the first query that i want (+ 1) but Hibernate in background, in order to get details about Students for each Course that select * given to us, will execute three more queries, one for each course (N, there are three Course coming from select *). In the end i will see 4 queries into Hibernate Logs

Considering the example before, probably this is what happen in your case: You execute the first query that you want, getting Configuration Id = 10 but after, Hibernate, will take the entity related to this Configuration, then a new query is executed to get this related entity.

This problem should be related in specific to Relationships (of course) and LAZY Fetch. This is not a problem that you have caused but is an Hibernate Performance Issue with LAZY Fetch, consider it a sort of bug or a default behaviour

To solve this kind of problem, i don't know if will be in your case but ... i know three ways:

- EAGER Fetch Type (but not the most good option)
- Query with JOIN FETCH between Courses and Students
- Creating EntityGraph Object that rappresent the Course and SubGraph that rappresent Students and is added to EntityGraph

Comment: I am not sure that i understand you, the fact is i never asked for Configuration object, i asked for ConfigurationTechLog object, what you can clearly see in my query, what i do not understand how and why extra query for Configuration is made, its really annoying

Comment: This is the point, is an Hibernate default property with Lazy stuff: When you are asking for only ConfigurationTech what Hibernate will do in automatic is to retrieve the Configuration Entity related to ConfigurationTech even if you haven't asked.

Although Hibernate and SQL share some properties, they aren't equal and they can't be comparable one to one. You are working with objects and not sql entities/query, this is a property done by default in Hibernate with objects relationships

Comment: Ok, so, We can say that Hibernate in automatic will get entities related to another asked by default even if you don't ask them (You don't see anything, in background instead there are differences), both in Lazy and Eager but from executed queries by Hibernate in background you will see respectively the N + 1 for Lazy and less query for Eager because it resolve relationships with less queries. You can't do anything to prevent extra data taken but you can fix the N +1, this is what i know ... they have built Hibernate in this way, is an ORM (Object Relationship Mapping) that work with Objects.

Comment: indeed, if in reality we think about it for a moment, what happen in SQL? Imagine to have SELECT * FROM ConfigurationTechLog where Id = 10. You are selecting all Columns to be shown, also the reference keys to others entities in other Table, in some way you are getting a value that is related to another entity although it is not complete

Comment: So in other words if i understood correctly, if i explicitly select fields that i need, for example fields from primary constructor in my case, new hibernate call won't be made ?


So if i go select new ConfigurationTechLog(c.id, c.something, c.somethingElse) from ConfigurationTechLog then it should work ?

Comment: In order to solve the N + 1 with Lazy Fetch, you need to change it in Eager Fetch or to have another approach like EntityGraph. The fact is that Hibernate always will take the information about another entity related to the desired entity if there is a relationship between them.

Comment: For the community and science anyway, we can try this theory derived by the example described before with reference key in SQL, please update us about what happen if we select only columns that aren't reference key to another entity.

We could theorize again and again but not with my bad english and Stackoverflow characters limit.

Comment: Consider also that N + 1 Problem is a Performance Issue but if your Application not need a Performance Tuning you can left this as is, not always something is needed, especially if is not a problem at all

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Kotlin data class. The kotlin data class would generate `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals` methods utilizing all the member fields. So if you are using the returned values in your code in a way that results in calling of any of these method may cause this issue.

BTW, using Kotlin data claases is against the basic requirements for JPA Entity as data classes are final classes having final members.

Comment: That is a good point, and now i see that i have data in my question, but actually i do not have it in my code, so with or without data i still see the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make an association lazy, Hibernate has to create a proxy instance instead of using the real object, i.e. it needs to create an instance of dynamically generated subclass of the association class.

Since in Kotlin all classes are final by default, Hibernate cannot subclass it so it has to create the real object and initialize the association right away. In order to verify this, try declaring the `Configuration` class as `open`.

To solve this without the need to explicitly declare all entities `open`, it is easier to do it via the [kotlin-allopen compiler plugin](https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/).

Comment: When i do that i get error in ConfigurationTechLog class, it says this:

'One To Many' attribute value type should not be '? extends Configuration'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, it seems like an expected behavior.

Since you've set up `configuration` to fetch lazily with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, the first sql just queries the other variables. When you try to access the `configuration` object, hibernate queries the db again. That's what lazy fetching is. If you'd like Hibernate to use joins and fetch all values at once, try setting `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`.

Comment: But the trick is i do not want and i do not access configuration object at all, as matter affect i want to avoid that, and if you see my query, there you can clearly see that i did not join Configuration object at all...

Comment: You've not mentioned the calling logic in the question. One thing I'd like to point out is that the `@Query` takes JPQL query defination and not native SQL. So, "if you see my query, there you can clearly see that i did not join Configuration object at all" is not correct. Maybe that's the root of your confusion here.

Comment: So you want to say that by Select C from ConfigurationTechLog C is selcting Configuration object, because i am asking for C and in C i have fetched configuration object, even i have JsonIgnore on it? I am really trying to understand what is happening here. I believe that i totally misunderstood how JsonIgnore works and Lazy joins...

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` simply ignores from serialization and deserialization to and from JSON. Basic use case might be while returning objects as REST resources. I don't think it can be used to ignore Hibernate persistence. The misunderstanding might be because you're using the same object to persist from db as well as return as REST resource. While JPA annotations as well as Jackson annotations might be used, they are working in totally separate layers.

Comment: Ok i understand, but can you tell me do you have idea WHERE and HOW i am requesting configuration object ? Since literally in my rest controller i simply call that method from repository, so there is no way that i used some kind of getter on COnfiguration object

Comment: On trying to return the object from the repository method call through your api, you've requested the configuration object. Once that part is done, when the object is being serialized as JSON response, it is ignored with jsonignore. 
See, if only lazy fetching discarded the configuration object, you wouldn't need jsonignore annotation but that's not the case.