# JPA Join over multiple Entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

My Problem is as follows

```
@Entity
public class MainType{
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SubType subObject;
}

@Entity
public class SubType{
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SubSubType subsubObject;
}
```

When I query the MainType with Hibernate to recieve a Collection hibernate will make a join. Something like
`select * from MainType left join SubType` which is good but then it makes another select for each record that the first query returned to load SubSubType. I would like to load everything in a single query like `select * from MainType left join SubType left join SubSubType`.

Do you know any way to make that happen?

Comment: How do you "query the MainType"?

Comment: @acm via Hibernates Criteria-API

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-hibernate) help you? Otherwise, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

In HQL/JPQL you'd write that almost as you mentioned:

```
SELECT mt FROM MainType mt 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH mt.subObject so 
  LEFT JOIN FETCH so.subSubObject sso
```

The key is to apply a `JOIN FETCH` and not just a `JOIN` to avoid the additional query that will fetch the objects after acquiring the identifiers.

Comment: Yes I thought about that way too. But i am Using the Criteria API for querying. And aditionally i want all the querys for MainType to look like this not only the one i am writing now. Isn't there a chance to force this way of querying inside the modeldeclaration.