# JpaRepository - getting rid of multiple selects using getAll()

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I`ve got 2 entities, where one is a field of another.

Country

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries", catalog = "librarydb")
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String countryName;
}
```

Author

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors", catalog = "librarydb")
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@SelectBeforeUpdate
public class Author {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;

}
```

AuthorRepository

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {}
```

So when I call authorRepository.getAll(); method from my controller I get multiple selects like:

```
Hibernate: select author0_.id as id1_0_, author0_.country_id as country_6_0_, author0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, author0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, from librarydb.authors author0_
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_0_, country0_.country_name as country_2_2_0_ from librarydb.countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_0_, country0_.country_name as country_2_2_0_ from librarydb.countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_0_, country0_.country_name as country_2_2_0_ from librarydb.countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_0_, country0_.country_name as country_2_2_0_ from librarydb.countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_0_, country0_.country_name as country_2_2_0_ from librarydb.countries country0_ where country0_.id=?
```

For me it seems that something goes realy wrong as if I would use Query with Join I would only use one SELECT and not multiple.
Anyone can clarify if this is a normal behavoir for Jpa? Any way to make it work correctly not spamming SELECT queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the solution for the N+1 issue in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-hibernate)

Comment: Why don't you define `private Country country;` as `@OneToOne` instead of `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: No it is not a duplicate as we talk of data-jpa and not hql joined query.

Comment: I clearly understand how to write appropriate joined query, but wonder if there is a way to do it via jpa getAll() method.

Comment: Yes you are right Michael, my mapping is excessive. Does it make any difference for the  query em executes in the current case?