# When should I use @EntityGraph in spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The `@EntityGraph` annotation will combine several SQL queries into a single query with JOIN if the target entity has other entity references.

```
class Hotel {
   int id;
   String name;
   City city;
}

class City {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

If I call method `hotelDao.findAllByName("hotelname")`, it will generate 2 queries :

- `select hotel.id hotel.name hotel.city.id from hotel;`
- `select city.id city.name from city where city.id={?};` // I think `?` is the list of city id of the first query result

If I annotated the method above with `@EntityGraph("city")`, it will generate 1 query instead:

- `select hotel.id hotel.name city.id city.name from hotel join city where hotel.cityid = city.id;`

I wonder which choice is better? The latter one is suggested by a lot of articles but I noticed that the join table would grow exponentially if the two tables are getting bigger.

So when should I use one over another and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to let Hibernate generate as few SQL queries as possible.

So `@EntityGraph` is a way to provide this kind of optimization.

The problem with multiple SQL queries is called n+1 select problem.

There are a lot of articles about this and how to solve it. One is on SO:
[What is the solution for the N+1 issue in JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-jpa-and-hibernate)