# Spring Data JPA query returns multiple CPCs instead of a single one

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, firebird

I'm using Spring Data JPA and have defined a native SQL query that is intended to retrieve a single CPC record for a given customer (KLIENCI) based on certain criteria. However, the query is returning a list of CPC records instead of a single one, which is not the expected behavior.

Here's the **SQL query** for reference:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT k.ID_KLIENT, k.NAZWA, k.EMAIL,  \n" +
        "\tc.ID_CPC , c.DATA_ROZLICZENIA, c.ID_MASZYNA, \n" +
        "\tm.ID_MASZYNA, m.MODEL, m.KOLOR  \n" +
        "FROM KLIENCI k \n" +
        "JOIN CPC c ON c.ID_KLIENT = k.ID_KLIENT \n" +
        "JOIN MASZYNY m ON m.ID_KLIENT  = k.ID_KLIENT AND m.ID_MASZYNA = c.ID_MASZYNA \n" +
        "WHERE c.DATA_ROZLICZENIA = (\n" +
        "\tSELECT MAX (c2.DATA_ROZLICZENIA)\n" +
        "\tFROM CPC c2 \n" +
        "\tWHERE  c2.ID_KLIENT  = k.ID_KLIENT AND c2.ID_MASZYNA = c.ID_MASZYNA \n" +
        ") AND k.ID_KLIENT = :customerId",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomerEntity> findCPCsForCustomer(@Param("customerId") int customerId);
```

This is how [*results*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FALt5.png) looks like in *DBeaver*:

However, Spring creates 3 queries instead of one, and returns all CPC for the specified customer:

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        k.ID_KLIENT,
        k.NAZWA,
        k.EMAIL,
        c.ID_CPC ,
        c.DATA_ROZLICZENIA,
        c.ID_MASZYNA,
        m.ID_MASZYNA,
        m.MODEL,
        m.KOLOR   
    FROM
        KLIENCI k  
    JOIN
        CPC c 
            ON c.ID_KLIENT = k.ID_KLIENT  
    JOIN
        MASZYNY m 
            ON m.ID_KLIENT  = k.ID_KLIENT 
            AND m.ID_MASZYNA = c.ID_MASZYNA  
    WHERE
        c.DATA_ROZLICZENIA = (
            SELECT
                MAX (c2.DATA_ROZLICZENIA)  
            FROM
                CPC c2   
            WHERE
                c2.ID_KLIENT  = k.ID_KLIENT 
                AND c2.ID_MASZYNA = c.ID_MASZYNA  
        ) 
        AND k.ID_KLIENT = ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        x1_0.id_klient,
        x1_0.id_maszyna,
        x1_0.kolor,
        x1_0.model 
    from
        maszyny x1_0 
    where
        x1_0.id_klient=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.id_klient,
        c1_0.id_cpc,
        c1_0.data_rozliczenia,
        c1_0.id_maszyna 
    from
        cpc c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.id_klient=?
```

**Customer class**

```java
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_KLIENT")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAZWA")
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<XeroEntity> xeroEntityList;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CPCEntity> cpcEntityList;
}
```

**Xero machine class**

```java
public class XeroEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_MASZYNA")
    private int id;

    private String model;

    @Column(name = "KOLOR")
    private String color;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_KLIENT")
    private CustomerEntity customerEntity;
}
```

**CPC class**

```java
public class CPCEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CPC")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ID_MASZYNA")
    private int xeroId;
    @Column(name = "DATA_ROZLICZENIA")
    private Date settlementDate;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_KLIENT")
    private CustomerEntity customerEntity;

}
```

Additionally, I attempted to use JPQL to address the issue, but encountered the same problem.

I've confirmed that the database schema is correct, and the expected result is a single CPC record per machine for a specific customer. However, the query is returning multiple CPC records. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm looking for guidance on how to modify the query or the repository method to return a single CPC as intended.

Comment: The query in your screenshot is not the same as the native query you set for `findCPCsForCustomer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom entity for this query, or only query that single CPC (whatever that is) and use `CPCEntity` or `List<CPCEntity>` as the return type. The problem is that you're creating a (normal) `CustomerEntity`, which means when you ask that entity for its `cpcEntityList`, it will query for and return **all** CPC entities associated with the customer, not just the one that you tried to query. That is why Hibernate executes that second and third query (your code probably queried both `xeroEntityList` **and** `cpcEntityList`).

In fact, for your first query, Hibernate ignored all the columns that did not map to the `CustomerEntity`: it only used the columns directly associated with `CustomerEntity`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark Rotteveel on the above.

Extending to his,

I highly recommend to create a view on the database with the same query as above (without the where clause), a projection interface for the view and call it from Repository.

But if for some reason the implementation cannot be altered, you can use @EntityGraph

- On the CustomerEntity class, implement the @NamedEntityGraph

  ```java
  @Entity
  @NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.customer.cpc", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("cpcEntityList"))
  public class CustomerEntity{//Entity members}
  ```
- And on the repository, you can implement the below

  ```java
  @Query(value = "SELECT k \n" +
      "FROM CustomerEntity k \n" +
      "JOIN k.cpcEntityList c \n" +
      "JOIN k.xeroEntityList m \n" +
      "WHERE (k.id = :customerId) and (m.id = c.xeroId) order by c.settlementDate desc limit 1",
      nativeQuery = false)
  @EntityGraph(value = "graph.customer.cpc")
  List<CustomerEntity> findCPCsForCustomer(@Param("customerId") int customerId);
  ```

Kindly note, this will still execute two queries, you are simply limiting the response of CPCEntity and will have challenges when a similar behaviour is expected out of XeroEntity

References:

[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521443/when-should-i-use-entitygraph-in-spring-data-jpa) --- Similar issue on stack overflow
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649418/hibernate-left-join-fetch-with-on-clause-or-alternative)

I hope this helps