# Spring boot won't use hibernates default_batch_fetch_size

Tags: spring, hibernate

Tried to configure hibernates `default_batch_fetch_size` through the spring `application.yml`.
AFAIK the setting has the same effect as putting `@BatchSize(size = xxx)` annotations on all your entity-relationships.

I enabled `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics: true` and logging accordingly and tried setting

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
          default_batch_fetch_size: 30
```

I also tried

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      default_batch_fetch_size: 30
```

but that configuration property doesn't seem to exist at all.

Resulting Logs show that hibernate won't fetch collections batched, but N+1 (FetchMode is not specified - thus the default `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` is used - and I don't want to change that).

Comment: How is the N+1-SELECT problem related to the batch size?

Comment: I thought it's at least somewhat related. i.e., see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456516/314089. But I agree that it's not necessarily  directly linked or a definitive answer for the N+1-SELECT problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was an unknown Hibernate feature for me.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I mixed up where to put the property-config. The right path is something like this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_batch_fetch_size: 30
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
```

Comment: What does the `jdbc.batch_size` property do?  What I guess is that it makes a `SELECT * FROM ( ) WHERE ROWNUM < 100` but I'm not sure of that