# Solution to N+1 issue in JPA and Hibernate with multiples Many-To-One

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, fetch

I found some solutions to avoid N+1 problem but this solutions works only for single Many-To-One relationship.

For example, the following question: [What is the solution for the N+1 issue in JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-jpa-and-hibernate)

The problem that I'm trying to solve is this:

```
@Entity 
public class Book implements Serializable { 
    
  @Id 
  private Long id; 

  private String title; 
    
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  private Author author; 

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  private Brand brand;
}
```

Solutions like try to fetch through JPQL doesn't work and fetch just one relationship, for example:

```
SELECT b FROM Book b 
INNER JOIN FETCH b.author 
INNER JOIN FETCH b.brand
```

In this case, only 'author' relationship would be fetched and N+1 problem will happen with 'brand' relationship.

**Do you know any solution to solve this specific problem?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with criteria api:

```
CritieriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Book> cq = cb.createQuery(Book.class);

Root<Book> root = cq.from(Book.class);
root.fetch("author"); //root.fetch(Book_.author) if use metamodel
root.fetch("brand"); //root.fetch(Book_.brand) if use metamodel

cq.select(root);

List<Book> result = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```