# How to use JPA Hibernate with tons of coupled entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working in a project and we have tons of data for each call that we are doing from the front-end to the back-end.

The thing is that we have a really huge database and we have tons of coupled entities.

For example, we have to bring the user, but it has an "address" object with a lot of information, and also this has a "city" object with more information, and then we have "zip code" same and so...

The thing is that we are facing some performance issues when we have some concurrent users. We are creating a query for each user, and then another one for each address, and then another one for each city... The thing is that when we are getting all the users all this nested objects, even if it's the same city, we create a SQL for each user.

Can we use something in hibernate to improve this performance?

Thank you so much
Best regards

Comment: Sounds like you want to lazy load the relationships

Comment: You will find a lot of posts on this performance strategy you can start with in this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-jpa-and-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

1. use Hibernate Second-Level Cache
2. Lazy loading
3. @Batch

Answer (score 0):

4. Use @EntityGraph if your tons of coupled entities are really not so huge.
5. For really big amounts of data (even with pagination) add findByEntityIds(ids) methods to all of your entity repositories. Collect all required ids, all required objects, construct DTOs programmactically (Java streams are helpful with "collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyDto::getId());".