# How to detect N+1 problems in a Hibernate/JPA application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given that [N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping) has been the most pernicious problem with Hibernate/JPA applications for about 20 years, I was hoping there's a way of detecting it (before it's too late). Something like the following:

- Install "N+1 detector" dependency
- Run the test suite
- The N+1 detector reports occurrences (or likely occurrences) of N+1 that were encountered during the test suite execution

I'm not sure how exactly this mythical N+1 detector would work, but if you could [proxy the database queries](https://github.com/jdbc-observations/datasource-proxy) and notice that the same query is being executed multiple times in quick succession, then that's a likely case of N+1.

However, I haven't actually found anything like this, does it exist? Is there any automated, or semi-automated way to detecting N+1?

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but in my specific case I'm using Spring Boot 3.X with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: For those wondering (like I was): [What is the "N+1 selects problem" in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping). I knew of the problem, I just didn't have a name for it. Good to know.

Comment: I don't know about a generic detector for that problem but it might be possible to do some analysis based on certain patters (like loading a list of object (without something like `FETCH JOIN`) and then accessing some lazily loaded collection. I guess the best would be checking all uses of lazily loaded collections and then finding where the entities come from... Alternatively, it might be possible to just log all SQL statements executed by the ORM and looking for many consecutive similar statements.

Comment: Or otherwise inject logic detecting consecutive SQL statements of the same kind and then filter lazily loaded collections.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I'm pretty familiar with how to detect and fix individual N+1 problems, but I've done it so many times now that I'm looking for a way to do the detection part automatically, system-wide. I accept that remediating such problems is probably beyond the scope of automation (for now).

Comment: As I said, I don't know any such tools (and asking for tools is off-topic here anyways) but I guess it would be possible to write something that analyzes things like that. However, that would probably lead to a lot of false positives.

Comment: @Dónal  I wonder, even such tool exists (actually, the first/second link in google: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/), how are you going to resolve "smells" discovered by that "detector"? The typical suggestions like adding graph hints, defining fetch joins implicitly, using projections, etc do not scale at all (like in order to solve the problem you need to write 10 repository methods instead of single one). In our projects we get rid off [Any]To[Any] associations completely, and our applications do not suffer anymore from N+1 problems.

Answer (score 0):

The N+1 problem is a common performance issue that occurs when fetching data from a database using an ORM framework like Hibernate or JPA.

There are several ways to detect and prevent the N+1 problem in Spring Boot applications using Spring Data JPA.

Here are some approaches:

1. Using `EntityGraph` annotations to specify which associations should be fetched eagerly or lazily.[Reference link](https://tech.asimio.net/2020/11/06/Preventing-N-plus-1-select-problem-using-Spring-Data-JPA-EntityGraph.html)
2. Using `AppMap` plugin for IntelliJ to visualize the queries executed by the ORM and identify the N+1 queries.[Reference link](https://appmap.io/blog/2021/10/04/detecting_n_plus_one_for_spring_applications/)
3. Using `DataLoader` pattern to batch and cache the queries for related entities.[Reference link](https://philipstarritt.medium.com/graphql-demystified-the-n-1-problem-a455e717de4d)
4. Using `JOIN FETCH` or `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` to fetch the main entities and their associations in one query.[Reference link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-hibernate-n1-problem)
5. Using `spring-hibernate-query-utils` library to auto-detect the N+1 queries in your application.[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453989/what-is-the-solution-for-the-n1-issue-in-jpa-and-hibernate)

I hope this helps you solve your problem.