# How to get rid of N+1 with JPA Criteria API in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I'm migrating our DAO from using Hibernate Criteria API to JPA Criteria API. I've got a class with several `@ManyToOne` there:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_TABLE", schema="SCHEMA_NAME")
public class A {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(SELECT * FROM (SELECT B.B_ID FROM SCHEMA_NAME.B_TABLE B WHERE B.A_ID = B_ID AND (B.B_CODE = '1' OR B.B_CODE = '2') ORDER BY B.B_CREATED_TIMESTAMP DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)")
    private B b1;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(SELECT * FROM (SELECT B.B_ID FROM SCHEMA_NAME.B_TABLE B WHERE B.A_ID = B_ID AND (B.B_CODE = '3' OR B.B_CODE = '4') ORDER BY B.B_CREATED_TIMESTAMP DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)")
    private B b2;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B_TABLE", schema="SCHEMA_NAME")
public class B {

}
```

In a query I'm using `JoinType.LEFT` in order to get rid of generated by default `CROSS JOIN`'s:

```
if (LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_ENTITIES.contains(field)) {
    path = ((From) path).join(field, JoinType.LEFT);
} else {
    path = path.get(field);
}
```

I'm getting right results, all the `A` and `B` records are retrieved correctly. However, after the migration I'm getting n+1 problem: all the `B` records are retrieved one-by-one despite using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s in generated queries. Previously (when using Hibernate Criteria API) Hibernate was able to satisfy the query without n+1 having the same joins in generated SQL.

Thank you for any ideas and help!

**UPDATE** As an example of using the `if-else` above for search by "b1.fieldName" I would get the following:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("b1", JoinType.LEFT).get("someFiled"), 42)
```

Comment: You should also provide JPA code. What type of fetch are you using?

Comment: @NiVeR actually, I'm using `.join`. It is in the `if-else` branch in the question) I'm just using `.join` if I encounter e.g. search by "b1.someField". It would be the same as `criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("b1", JointType.LEFT).get("someField"), 42)`

Comment: You can use fetch join (better) or @BatchSize(size = x)

Comment: @Samoth interesting idea. but it is `@ManyToOne`. should I use `@BatchSize(size = 1)`? regarding fetch join: it always will be eager, right? and do you mean `.fetch` method or some annotation?

Comment: Yes, it will be eager. You can use it in HQL, eg. select u from User u JOIN FETCH u.addresses.  BatchSize for ManyToOne: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048436/manytoone-and-batchsize

Comment: @Samoth seems like in that case I would get batching for this `b1`, `b2` and etc fields. But previously Hibernate was able to load this fields with the query for `A` without any additional queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The N+1 issue comes from the default [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) fetching strategy of the `@ManyToOne` associations.

So, you need to switch to `FetchType.LAZY`, like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula("(SELECT * FROM (SELECT B.B_ID FROM SCHEMA_NAME.B_TABLE B WHERE B.A_ID = B_ID AND (B.B_CODE = '1' OR B.B_CODE = '2') ORDER BY B.B_CREATED_TIMESTAMP DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)")
private B b1;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula("(SELECT * FROM (SELECT B.B_ID FROM SCHEMA_NAME.B_TABLE B WHERE B.A_ID = B_ID AND (B.B_CODE = '3' OR B.B_CODE = '4') ORDER BY B.B_CREATED_TIMESTAMP DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1)")
private B b2;
```

If you want to automatically detect N+1 issues automatically that might affect other parts of your application, then you can use [`datasource-proxy`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/).

If you need to fetch the association eagerly with Criteria API, then you should use `fetch` instead of `join`.

```
if (LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_ENTITIES.contains(field)) {
    path = ((From) path).fetch(field, JoinType.LEFT);
} else {
    path = path.get(field);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it is very useful, especially the article. But I need to fetch the records eager. I managed to solve the issue using `.fetch` on the `CriteriaQuery`'s `root`

Comment: Then you should use fetch instead of join.

Comment: it generates `CROSS JOIN`s otherwise. I have to use both

Comment: works as expected, thank you! besides the `path = ((From) path).fetch(field, JoinType.LEFT);` - `.fetch` returns `Fetch` and it doesn't compile